# QT Creator fails to parse a very easy project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, projects-and-solutions

I created a very simple project in QT creator, *.pro file is just following:

```
HEADERS += inc\1.h
SOURCES += src\1.cpp
```

Here is the source code:

```
// 1.h
const int C = 1;

// 1.cpp
#include "1.h"

int main() {
    return C;
}
```

QT Creator successfully opens this "project", but cannot parse it. F2 does not work for C constant, 1.h header cannot be found.

Please look at the screenshot which describes the problem:

[image: Screenshot showing the project structure]

The most strange part is that exactly the same thing seems to work on my other machine with similar QT SDK 5.0 installation! Could you please advise where am I wrong?

Comment: Should it be `#include "inc/1.h"`?

Comment: No, I hope it should not. Maybe you mean "../inc/1.h" - this works, but I need my includes to be found without full paths to them. Why do I need "HEADERS" part of the .pro file if I must specify full path?

Comment: Adding inc folder to INCLUDE_PATH does not work either. The strangest part is that the same project is parsed well on the very similar other machine. I have problem with includes and syntax parsing on a big project where I am not able to modify #include directives, so I created this simple example to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Could be completely unrelated, but I was seeing this error and no source files were showing up in the project. After setting the correct path for the "Qt version" in the current Kit (`/usr/bin/qmake-qt5` for me) suddenly everything appeared.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HEADERS` is supposed to list the header files of your own project, just like `SOURCES` lists the source files.

If you want to include external header files, you should add their folders to `INCLUDEPATH` instead:

```
INCLUDEPATH += inc
```

The following .pro file works perfectly in Qt Creator 2.5.0, Qt 4.6.1:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
    src/1.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += inc
```

Try that exact .pro file, give it 3 seconds to parse and tell me if it worked.

Comment: I tried the approach with INCLUDEPATH, it does not work on my computer as well. Maybe it is some kind of strange heisenbug in the newest QT, I don't know. I will try previous v4 SDK and tell you)

Comment: Can you compile it? And are you using Qt Creator 2.6.1 on the other machine (where it works) as well?

Comment: Thank you very much for advises, I tried to compile it and it failed and I realized that my QT "Kit" (whatever it is) does not have a default compiler. Compiler should definitely be used to parse the sources so I think this was the root cause. Now everything works perfectly well.

Comment: I did not try to compile projects because I just wanted to use the Creator to work with big project that uses external build system.